# "Ebenso Tausende"?

Tags: word-usage

> 56.000 Rosen und Nelken sind schon in der Erde, **ebenso Tausende** Bäume und Sträucher.

Nach meinem Empfinden hört sich der Satz falsch an. Kann man nach einem Wort wie "ebenso" auch "Dutzende","Hunderte" oder "Millionen" verwenden?

Comment: Ja, kann man. "Ebenso" wird ja wie "ausserdem" benutzt. Ich finde den Satzbau nicht besonders elegant für Schriftsprache, aber das "ebenso" macht da keinen Unterschied.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ja, denn das Wort *»ebenso«* wird hier als kopulatives Konjunktionaladverb verwendet. Man kann es hier ohne Veränderung der Bedeutung auch durch *»auch«* ersetzen:

> 56.000 Rosen und Nelken sind schon in der Erde, **auch** Tausende Bäume und Sträucher.

Das ist eine verkürzte Form des folgenden Satzes:

> 56.000 Rosen und Nelken sind schon in der Erde, **auch** Tausende Bäume und Sträucher sind schon in der Erde.

Das Wort *»auch«* lässt auch eine andere Reihenfolge der Wörter zu:

> 56.000 Rosen und Nelken sind schon in der Erde, **auch** sind schon Tausende Bäume und Sträucher in der Erde.

In dieser Reihung kann auch in der langen Version *»auch«* durch *»ebenso«* ersetzt werden:

> 56.000 Rosen und Nelken sind schon in der Erde, **ebenso** sind schon Tausende Bäume und Sträucher in der Erde.

Wenn man nun die doppelten Teile *»sind schon«* und *»in der Erde«* weglässt, entsteht der (völlig korrekte) Satz aus deiner Frage.

Andere kopulative Konjunktionaladverbien (neben *»auch«* und *»ebenso«*) sind:

- **außerdem**

  > 56.000 Rosen und Nelken sind schon in der Erde, **außerdem** Tausende Bäume und Sträucher.
- **ferner**

  > 56.000 Rosen und Nelken sind schon in der Erde, **ferner** Tausende Bäume und Sträucher.
- **zudem**

  > 56.000 Rosen und Nelken sind schon in der Erde, **zudem** Tausende Bäume und Sträucher.
- **überdies**

  > 56.000 Rosen und Nelken sind schon in der Erde, **überdies** Tausende Bäume und Sträucher.
- **ebenfalls**

  > 56.000 Rosen und Nelken sind schon in der Erde, **ebenfalls** Tausende Bäume und Sträucher.
- **gleichfalls**

  > 56.000 Rosen und Nelken sind schon in der Erde, **gleichfalls** Tausende Bäume und Sträucher.

Das Zahlwort dahinter spielt keine Rolle, es steht grammatikalisch in keinem Zusammenhang mit der Konjunktion.

Answer (score 4):

Ja, denn der Begriff "Tausende" steht zwar *nach* dem "ebenso", aber er *bezieht sich nicht darauf*.

Der häufigste Gebrauch von "ebenso" verwendet ein prädikatives Adjektiv:

> Der neue Standard ist *ebenso unbrauchbar* wie der alte.

Man kann es aber auch verwenden, um ganze Sätze zu reihen. In dieser Weise ist der Beispielsatz zu verstehen: Rosen und Nelken sind in der Erde, und Bäume und Sträucher sind *ebenfalls/auch/ebenso/gleichfalls*/etc. schon in der Erde. Die gleichlautenden
Bestandteile der beiden Sätze werden gern weggelassen, da mn sie erschliessen kann.

Die Bäume sind also nicht "ebenso tausend" wie die Blumen, was keinen Sinn ergäbe, sondern das "ebenso" bezieht sich auf die Gesamtaussage: "A ist B und C ist ebenfalls B". (Vgl. Monty Python 1979: "Ich bin Brian, und meine Frau ist auch Brian!)